# Show the user email address automatically in a form, when the user will click in a html email template

Tags: php, html, mysql, email

Hello StackOverflowers,

Right now I have a Button, if I press on that button a HTML email will be sent to 50 e-mail addresses.

I'm sending this mail with PHP mailer, and the email addresses are stored in a database: I will send the template.html as body message, in there they will see a email where they have  to  click to " confirm their email address." But I want that if each user will click on the Link "Click here to confirm" a link/page will be opened, but that i want to show the value of the email address in that page already so that will be automatically filled in of the user's email address, so that they only have to type the password and press confirm.

So if they press on " Click here to confirm now " They will see this page: http://jsfiddle.net/ry8g20e6/1/ with their email adress in there, so that tehy only have to fill the password, and hit confirm

This is the php code from sending to the users from the database

```
if( isset($_POST['button_pressed']) )
{

mysql_connect("localhost","dbuser","dbpass");
mysql_select_db("dbname");

$rs=mysql_query("select * FROM test");

// Do while loop to send email.
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($rs))


    $to=$row['email'];

    $subject = "Confirm your account"; 
    $message.= file_get_contents("template.html") ;
```

So that means they will receive the email with the **template.html** as body message.

So the **template.html** contains this message :

Hello User, Click here to confirm your email adress ( when they click on that they will see this page to confirm their email adres: http://jsfiddle.net/ry8g20e6/1/ ) But how i can do that their email address will be automaticlly showed into the email value? So that they only will have to type their password and hit send?

So I want that if the user will receive the email with the (template.html) file and if they click on the link with: Confirm your email address, then a new page / (custom form ) will be opened: http://jsfiddle.net/ry8g20e6/1/  and that the value of his email address will be already added in the form??

```
<p>Email: 
  <input name="emailadress" type="text" id="emailadress" value="theuseremailadres@here.com>
</p>
<p>Password:
  <input type="text" name="password" id="password">
  <input type="button" name="sbumit" id="submit" value="Confirm">
```

> So actually i if the user pres on "Click here to confirm" this page above will be opened, and in want that the user email adress will already showed in the value of the email adress input

The template.html will contains something like this:

```
<body>
<p>Hello User, Click <a href="confirm.php">here</a> to confirm your email adress</p>
</body>
```

> update

So i have now this:

index.php:

```
$rs=mysql_query("select * FROM test");

// Do while loop to send email.
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($rs))


    $to=$row['email'];

    $subject = "Hello This is a Test"; 
    $message.= file_get_contents("template.html") ;
```

template.html:

```
<body>
<p>Click <a href="confirm.php?email={$to}">here</a> to confirm your email adress</p>
</body>
```

confirm.php :

```
<p>Email: 
  <input name="email" type="text" id="email" value="" <?php $_GET['email'] ?> >
</p>
<p>Password:
  <input type="text" name="password" id="password">
  <input type="button" name="sbumit" id="submit" value="Confirm">
```

I don;t know where the problem is, if i send a test email, i will receive template.html as message .. And if i click on click here.. Confirm.php will be opened, but the email address will not appear automatically in the Email field.. Can someone help me out with this please?

Comment: the link in the email should have an id- that matches the user email in the db, then you can check that on the landing page and fill in the details.

Comment: side note: be real careful sending 5k emails a once

Comment: @Dagon http://stackoverflow.com/q/30492546/ wink

Comment: @Dagon Thanks for your note, @ wink your link isnt' working

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like

```
$to = $row['email'];
ob_start();
include "email_template.php";
$message = ob_get_clean();
```

and `email_template.php` is something like

```
<body>
<p>Click <a href="confirm.php?email={$to}">here</a> to confirm your email adress</p>
</body>
```

or maybe I'm completely wrong your post is very hard to follow.

edit:

following, `confirm.php` can access the email via `$_GET['email']`. Just replace the value of the input field for email.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I'm sorry for my hard question, i just want that if the user who will receive the email will press on the link for confirm, they will click on " Click here to confirm "  they if they press that a link will be open with a form, but i want to already include the user emailadress in the in the form, so that they only have to type the password and hit confirm, Something like this : http://jsfiddle.net/ry8g20e6/1/ Thanks for you help, I appreciate that!